# How to Export Oracle Table to SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have seen some hints on the web on how to Exporting Oracle DB using Oracle SQL Developer. Now my question is instead of exporting whole Database is there any option to export Only one Table let say "Emp" with all it's data and attributes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply right-click the table name in the Connections tree, and select "Export...". A new dialog box will open up for you to select various options.

There is a demonstration available [here](http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLDeveloper/html/module5/mod05_cp_exportdata.htm).

Comment: You're welcome Behseini!